# Made a crosshair randomizer that posts to clipboard, but it won't build or debug (c++)

Tags: c++

I've made a crosshair randomizer for csgo that also posts the string to my clipboard and i'm wondering why it won't debug or build?
I've included the external library and can't find anything simple that is wrong.
I'm sort of new, been a year since i coded.

This is the library i'm using: <https://github.com/Arian8j2/ClipboardXX
This is the console when i debug and the error list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ASpi.jpg

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <clipboardxx.hpp>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    bool running = true;


    while (running == true)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        float chSize = rand() % 4;
        int chThickness = rand() % 1;
        int chDot = rand() % 1;
        int chOutline = rand() % 1;
        float chOutlineThickness = rand() % 1;
        int chAlpha = rand() % 155 + 101;
        int chStyle = rand() % 6 + 3;
        int chGap = rand() % -12 + 13;
        int chWeaponGap = rand() % 1;
        string answer = "0";

        string crosshairCode = "cl_crosshairsize " + chSize + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairthickness " + chThickness + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairdot " + chDot + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshair_drawoutline " + chOutline + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshair_outline_thickness " + chOutlineThickness + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairalpha " + chAlpha + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairstyle " + chStyle + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairgap " + chGap + "; "
                             + "cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue " + chWeaponGap + "; ";

        clipboardxx::clipboard clipboard;
        clipboard << crosshairCode;
        string paste_text;
        clipboard >> paste_text;
        cout << "Here is your crosshaircommand: ";
        cout << crosshairCode;
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "It has been pasted to your clipboard aswell!" << endl;
        cout << "Do you want a new crosshair?" << endl;
        cout << "Answer (Y/N): ";
        cin >> answer;

        if (answer == "Y" || "y")
            {
            system("cls");
            running = true;
            }
        else if (answer == "N" || "y")
            {
            system("cls");
            running = false;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't concatenate a number to a string without converting it to a string first. `std::to_string` can do that but in this case it's easier to use string streams:

```
ostringstream ss; // output string stream
ss << "cl_crosshairsize " << chSize << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairthickness " << chThickness << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairdot " << chDot << "; "
   << "cl_crosshair_drawoutline " << chOutline << "; "
   << "cl_crosshair_outline_thickness " << chOutlineThickness << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairalpha " << chAlpha << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairstyle " << chStyle << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairgap " << chGap << "; "
   << "cl_crosshairgap_useweaponvalue " << chWeaponGap << "; ";
string crosshairCode = ss.str();
```

You need `#include <sstream>` to use it.